# Springsource tool suite or roo The directory or file cannot be created problem

Tags: spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am having a strange problem with sts and spring roo version 1.1.1 RELEASE. It has worked well for my project but since I had a viral infection on winxp I started experiencing random roo problems. I have tried a lot of suggestions like clean build my roo project, close and open, restart sts and even reinstalled sts to no avail.
Now I keep getting the error, well not actually an error "The directory or file cannot be created". As a result the ITD files are not being created at all. I have installed an uptodate antivirus and even checked manually if there is any process locking my roo project directory, there is none. An upgrade to roo 1.1.4 doesnt help either.
Any pointers on what could the problem would a appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roo Console usually watches your working directory to see if there is any file that has been changed in order to auto-generate files.

This appears to be a problem with the write permissions in your working directories or a possible case of disk corruption which prevents the above from happening.

Please try to get your computer into normal working state and fix your file system after getting a complete backup of your Spring Roo Project.

All the best with Spring Roo.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it was actually a hard disk problem, bought a new laptop and roo is working really well, actually I have really had luck with spring roo and am almost through with my project :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Happy to hear that Roo is getting you through. :)